# Insertion of image file to varbinary (max) field in ms sql server using php

Tags: php, sql-server-2005

I am able to convert image to binary format

```
**<?php
//$id = $_GET[‘id’];
//using sql query or other source get the dynamic image name or path
$path = ‘../images/rose.jpg’;
$size = GetImageSize($path);
$mime = $size['mime'];
$data=file_get_contents($path);
header("Content-type: $mime");
 header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($data));
 echo $data;
?>**
```

How can I insert the binary format in ms sql server 2005 using php

Thanks for your time.

Comment: what code you tried to insert?

Comment: Why can't you store a `blob`? or the relative link in the database and the respective image within the file system ?

Comment: $path = site_url().'/'."ext_gallery05.jpg";
        $size = GetImageSize($path);
        $mime = $size['mime'];
        $data=file_get_contents($path);
        header("Content-type: $mime");
        header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($data));
           $sql= "INSERT INTO Family_Members_Details([ID],[AppID],[MemberID],[MemberName],[SexID],[Age],[RelationID],[Status],[Photo],[Display])
                     VALUES(1,'$uhid','$memberid1','$name1','$sexid1','$age1','$relationid1' ,'0',0xABFD00057401675B455F72655D0D0A3C6543736F6E5F4C6F636174696F6,'Y');";

Comment: @Russell my client needs them to be in binary format